# Print smallest name with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am facing a problem with javascript problem-solving.
I am now trying to print out the smallest name from a named array. But I cannot print out it. It shows the different names. Would you mind helping me, please?

see the codes.

```js
var tinyFriend = ["hasan", "md", "mdhasan", "zahdhasan"];
var tiny = tinyFriend[0];
for (var i = 0; i < tinyFriend.length; i++) {
  var char = tinyFriend[i];
  if (char < tiny) {
    tiny = char;
  }
}
console.log(tiny);
```

please tell me where to make the correction

Comment: ```tinyFriend.sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length);```

Comment: `char.length < tiny.length`

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [Reduce Method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
var tinyFriend = ['hasan' , 'md' , 'mdhasan' , 'zahdhasan'];
var tiny = tinyFriend.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.length <= b.length ? a : b;
  });
console.log(tiny)
```

Answer (score 1):

use the inbuilt `sort` method

```js
var tinyFriend = ["hasan", "md", "mdhasan", "zahdhasan"];
var tiny = tinyFriend.sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length)[0];
console.log(tiny);
```

fix for original code

```
var tinyFriend = ["hasan", "md", "mdhasan", "zahdhasan"];
var tiny = tinyFriend[0];
for (var i = 0; i < tinyFriend.length; i++) {
  var char = tinyFriend[i];
  if (char.length < tiny.length) { // use length
    tiny = char;
  }
}
console.log(tiny);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [for-of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop here to get the smallest string in an array

```js
var tinyFriend = ["hasan", "md", "mdhasan", "zahdhasan"];

let smallest;
for (let word of tinyFriend) {
  if (smallest !== undefined) smallest = word.length < smallest.length ? word : smallest;
  else smallest = word;
}

console.log(smallest);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making mistake in these two lines `for (var i = 0; i <tinyFriend.length; i++) {` & `if (char < tiny) {`
You have assigned `tinyFriend[0];` to `tiny` so no need to start loop from `0`. Instead start from 1. Secondly here `if (char < tiny) {` you need to check `length`

Here is my solution. Inside  the loop just check if the length of the current name is smaller than the previous, then assign that name to `tiny`

```js
var tinyFriend = ["hasan", "md", "mdhasan", "zahdhasan"];
var tiny = tinyFriend[0];
for (var i = 1; i < tinyFriend.length; i++) {
  tiny = tiny.length > tinyFriend[i].length ? tinyFriend[i] : tiny;
}
console.log(tiny);
```